# make SQL Report hidden parameter visible when creating subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

is there a way to make a hidden parameter visible in SSRS Subscription creation ?

Something like this[image]

The Parameter IsSchedule will be hidden/internal(not visible to normal users) but should be visible when i create a schedule for the report.

Note: the reason i want this to be possible is for my SQL to know wether the data request it is getting is for a sql report schedule or for a person who is trying to view the report.

this way my SQL query will know if the End Date parameter data should/shouldn't be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see all `Hidden` parameters in the `Create a Subscription` wizard, which you can then assign a value to.

If the new parameter simply doesn't show up, you may need to delete and re-deploy the report:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/337c7ae9-f15a-4718-9fac-e5c1d6a73f30/boolean-default-parameter?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Updated answer.